# How to POST a form containing Editor Templates for an ICollection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working with ASP.NET MVC 4 and I have the following models:

```
public class MultiLanguageText
{
    [Key] public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required] public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<LocalizedText> LocalizedTexts { get; set; }
}

public class LocalizedText
{
    [Key] public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Language")] public int LanguageId { get; set; }
    public virtual Language Language { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("MultiLanguageText")] public int MultiLanguageTextId { get; set; }
    public virtual MultiLanguageText MultiLanguageText { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to create an Edit view for `MultiLanguageText` which will also contain an editor for every item in the `LocalizedTexts` property. The form goes like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "MultiLanguageText", FormMethod.Post)) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>MultiLanguageText</legend>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LocalizedTexts)
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

The editor template I've created (in the file `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/LocalizedText.cshtml`) is the following:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>LocalizedText</legend>
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LanguageId)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LanguageId)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LanguageId)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MultiLanguageTextId)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MultiLanguageTextId)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MultiLanguageTextId)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Text)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Text)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Text)
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

I'm testing with some pre-existing values and all the data is shown properly in the parent and in the child editors, when the page is shown. However, when I submit the form, all changes done inside any of the child editors are ignored.

My `HttpPost` method is this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(MultiLanguageText multilanguagetext)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(multilanguagetext).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(multilanguagetext);
    }
```

My question is: **How do I make it so that all values are posted, from both the parent model and its children model editors?** (I've seen that other similar questions exist, but I've tried their solutions and they didn't seem to fix my problem.)

Comment: Could you provide a little more information? What do the posted key/value pairs look like? Is the collection being populated, but with default values? Or is it empty? Or is it null?

Comment: I'm testing with seeded values, in which the collection is not empty. Data is retrieved successfully from the database. The editor templates show up properly and with the correct values. The problem is that any changes in the collection are not saved when submitting he form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trying, this is the solution that I found to work:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(MultiLanguageText multilanguagetext)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(multilanguagetext).State = EntityState.Modified;
            foreach (var local in multilanguagetext.LocalizedTexts) db.Entry(local).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(multilanguagetext);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm testing your question. I think it's done and all values posted. But I think you need provide more information to fix your problem

Comment: There isn't really much else to this project, because it's a testing project I'm using to learn MVC on. Is there anything specific you suspect that I should include in the question?